# How to fit large table in memory?

Tags: java, performance

I have a Java `Map<String, List<String>>`.

Is there a way to improve this to make it use less memory without having too much impact on performance?

Comment: If a lot of your strings are the same, i.e. many values are something like `"RED"`, then interning the strings will share them. Otherwise, no.

Comment: http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/memory/string_saving_memory.shtml

Comment: The answer will depend a lot on what your data looks like and what your access patterns are.

Comment: It may help to provide an example of the keys and values and some idea of how many there are as well as any patterns that you expect, since the question is very vague otherwise.  Also, is your problem that the Map won't fit into memory at all and you need to shrink it, or do you just want to reduce the memory requirements of an application that already works?

Comment: Dear Chris Martin, If you can't answer it, don't edit it and put it on Hold.  Thanks.  There is a perfectly legit answer below from Stephen C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three ideas:

- An encoded byte array could provide a less memory-intensive representation than a string, especially if the string data actually uses an 8 bit (or less) character set.
- A list of strings could be represented as a single string with a distinguished string separator character between the list components.
- String data is often compressible.

Depending on the nature of your data, these could easily give a 2 fold reduction in space for the lists.

The downside is that you may need to fully or partially reconstruct the original `List<String>` objects, which would be a performance hit.

You should also consider using a non-memory resident representation; e.g. a conventional database, a NOSQL database or an "object cache" framework.  JVMs with really large heaps tend to lead to performance problems if you need to do a "full" garbage collection, or if there is competition for physical memory with other applications.

Comment: Thanks Stephen! those are some amazing suggestions

Answer (score 0):

One would really need to know a lot more on your specific application to definitely recommend a specific solution, but as a wild guess, if it is a really, really large table (e.g hundreds of thousands or millions of records),  I would suggest you consider using a database to store data and access via one of data layer access abstractions, such as DataSet. 
Databases are already optimized to efficiently store, search and  access data over an amortized data and time range, so without further info on your application, I would go with this option.